# Get Children in JSON DataSnapshot

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the children from my JSON separately and pass them through an intent. Here is how my JSON is formatted:

```
  "allDeeJays" : {
    "-LeP1DB6Onzh4-UiN_0E" : {
      "acct" : "Aaron A",
      "djName" : "uhgvvvbbb"
    }
  },
```

Using the DataSnapshot, I have been able to get the `djName` values, but I am not getting the `acct` values, with the following code:

```
 @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        // Here you convert the DataSnapshot to whatever data your ViewHolder needs
                        String s = "";
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            s = ds.getValue(String.class);
                            DjProfile model = new DjProfile(s);
                            model.setDjName(s);

                            holder.setDjProfile(model);
                        }

                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {

                                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("allDeeJays");

                                String acct = "";
                                String name = "";

                                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                                {
                                    name = ds.getValue(String.class);
                                    acct = ds.getValue(String.class);
                                    DjProfile model = new DjProfile(name);
                                    model.setDjName(name);
                                }
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), AddSongRequest.class);
                                i.putExtra("DjName", name);
                                i.putExtra("UserAcct", acct);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
```

Finally, my DjProfile class is defined as follows: 
package com.example.android.heydj;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

```
public class DjProfile
{
    String djName;
    String key;


    public DjProfile(String djName)
    {
        this.djName = djName;
    }
    public DjProfile(){}

    public void setDjName(String djName)
    {
        this.djName = djName;
    }

    public String getdjName()
    {
        return djName;
    }
}
```

Both variables are returning the same value, and when I run `snapshot.getChildrenCount()` it says that there are two children (which I assume are acct, and djName). Do I need to add additional getters and setters for the account name? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Given that you're assigning the same `ds.getValue(String.class);` value to both `name` and `acct`, it makes sense that those variables have the same value. Aside from that, it is impossible to say what's going on without seeing both the code of your listener, where you attach it to, and the minimal `DjProfile` class with which you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this and it's will return exact value for your keys

```
if(snapShot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("djName"))
name = ds.getValue(String.class);

if(snapShot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("acct"))
acct = ds.getValue(String.class);
```

or use

```
  DjProfile model = snapShot.getValue(DjProfile.class);
```

instead of

```
 for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                name = ds.getValue(String.class);
                                acct = ds.getValue(String.class);
                                DjProfile model = new DjProfile(name);
                                model.setDjName(name);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by adding below line -

```
DjProfile profile = ds.getValue(DjProfile.class);
```

You can now pass this profile into an Intent.